# php Fatal error: Cannot use positional argument after named argument

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a cart for an e-commerce website. Here I am trying to insert the product ID and the user ID to the cart table in my database. I'm guessing I'm not using the impolde correctly.

```
public function inserIntoCart($para = null, $table = "cart")
{
    if($this->db->con != null){
        if($para != null){

            $columns = implode(glue: ',', array_keys($para));
            
            $values = implode(glue: ',', array_values($para));
            

            $query_string = sprintf(format: "INSERT INTO %s(%s) VALUES (%s)", $table, $columns, $values);

            $result = $this->db->query($query_string);
            return $result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove `glue:` you can add use it as a variable i.e `$glue = ',';`. Heres an example on how it would look, `implode($glue, array_keys($para));`

Also your `$query_string` variable that make reference to `sprintf` function is incorrect remove the word `format:` from the first argument. i.e `sprintf("INSERT INTO %s(%s) VALUES (%s)", $table, $columns, $values);`

Make sure to use the [docs](https://www.php.net/docs.php) as a reference.

A good way to debug is to use `var_dump($value);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is not with `implode` as such, but with how to use [named arguments](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.named-arguments).

As of PHP 8.0, you can use the `name: $value` syntax to pass named arguments in any order, but you need to follow certain rules:

- The names for the arguments must match the function definition
- If you mix named arguments with positional arguments (normal arguments with no `name:` before them), the positional ones have to come *first*

In this case:

- [The manual page for `implode`](https://www.php.net/implode) shows the arguments as named `separator` and `array`, so `glue` is not a valid name. (The manual used to call them `glue` and `pieces`, but this was [updated to match the names in the 8.0 implementation in Jan 2021](https://github.com/php/doc-en/commit/3c969c420f1232ac0946c70d3d6bb90d7f4e9c31).)
- You've given a name for your first argument, but not your second (which is what your error message says).

So the following would all be acceptable:

```
// Normal positional arguments
$columns = implode(',', array_keys($para));
// Positional first argument, named second argument
$columns = implode(',', array: array_keys($para));
// Name both arguments, in either order
$columns = implode(separator: ',', array: array_keys($para));
$columns = implode(array: array_keys($para), separator: ',');
```